# How do I setup DHCP on a 2nd port?

Tags: usb, raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, ethernet-port

### My Main Question

How do I configure my RPi so that I can share its internet connection with an IoT device plugged in via ethernet cable **in addition** to sharing its internet connection via its wifi-adapter?

### My Setup

I have multiple IoT devices that need internet access. Most are wireless, but one requires a wired ethernet connection. I have an RPi running Raspbian stretch with a static IP issued by my organization's network admin. The connection to my org network is via ethernet cable, and uses the built-in ethernet port on the RPi. It is `eth0` in my configuration. The RPi itself has no trouble connecting to the internet.

I was able to configure the RPi as a wireless access point using [this tutorial](https://howtoraspberrypi.com/create-a-wi-fi-hotspot-in-less-than-10-minutes-with-pi-raspberry/). That works great. My wireless IoT devices can connect to the wifi network on my RPi without issue.

For the wired device, I purchased [a USB ethernet adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IKSVAMQ) that shows up as `eth1`.

**I'm trying to setup `eth1` so that any device that is plugged into it will automatically be given an IP address and have access to the internet.**

Here are the current contents of key files (or ones that appear to be "key files" to me):

```
# /etc/network/interfaces
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
```

```
# /etc/dhcpcd.conf
hostname
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option ntp_servers
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
nohook lookup-hostname

# RaspAP-WebGui wireless configuration
interface wlan0
static ip_address=10.3.141.1/24
static routers=10.3.141.1
static domain_name_server=1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

```
# /etc/rc.local
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP Address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward #RASPAP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE #RASPAP
exit 0
```

```
# /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

### What I've Tried

I'm a web developer and don't have enough background in networking to have more than a bare grasp of what I'm trying to do. Essentially what I believe is that I need to setup `eth1` to act as a DHCP server for anything that connects to it, and then allow it to bridge to my internet connection which comes in via `eth0`. I tried to mimic the settings for `wlan0` with `eth1`.

Of course, I've done a lot of googling, but I never fully feel like I understand the reasoning behind the various configurations I've been reading, and therefore am not sure what I should try next.

I tried adding `eth1` to the `br0` bridge by adding `bridge_ports eth0 eth1` to `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I tried assigning different static IP addresses to `eth1` in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. Here are the addresses that I've tried (both with and without having it be a part of the bridge):

```
# first try
interface eth1
static ip_address=10.4.141.1/24
static routers=10.4.141.1
static domain_name_server=1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8

# second try
interface eth1
static ip_address=10.3.141.2/24
static routers=10.3.141.2
static domain_name_server=1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8

# third try
interface eth1
static ip_address=192.168.2.3/24
static routers=192.168.2.3
static domain_name_server=1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

I was successful at getting `eth1` to assign an IP address (in the host org network's IP address range) to a computer that I connected to it, but I haven't yet been able to also get internet access through that connection. Not only that, usually when I do this, though, my RPi loses internet access altogether, but not immediately. It will have internet access for a few seconds/minutes when it first boots up, but then loses it.

It feels like I'm really close, but I'm missing some key piece of understanding about how this stuff works.

Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: With the current config the **wlan0** interface is bridged with the **eth0** interface and devices on **wlan0** get their ip address from the DHCP server on the organization's network, isn't it? Can you confirm this?

Comment: Oh! Yes, I suppose so. The IP address of devices connected to **wlan0** is within the organization's IP range, so that must be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in a comment, devices connected to the access point (**wlan0**) get an ip address from the subnet of the organization's network. This is given by the bridge **br0** with member interfaces **wlan0** and **eth0**. It also implies that there is a DHCP server running on the organization's network that serves the devices connected to the bridge. Currently this are only devices connected to the access point. This also means there is no need for a second DHCP server that serves devices on **eth1**. Just adding interface **eth1** to the bridge as third member interface should do the job. Then it will also become member of the broadcast domain (subnet) from the organization's network like **wlan0**. So far in theory.

Since years I haven't used old style networking you have configured so my practical knowledge is limited with it and I don't have a test environment for it. You have to add **eth1** to the bridge as member the same way you did with **wlan0** and **eth0**. As far as I can see you only have to modify in `/etc/network/interfaces` the line:

```
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
# to
bridge_ports eth0 eth1 wlan0
```

Comment: It worked!!! So simple, and I was so close. I had tried to bridge `eth0` to `eth1` on a separate line rather than putting all three interfaces on the same line. Thank you so much!